# Stream gstreamer to vlc freeze issue

Tags: streaming, gstreamer, h.264, vlc, rtp

I've got a problem trying to receive gstreamer stream with VLC.
This is the command I use for transmitting:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=vid.h264 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! \
     udpsink host=192.168.1.10 port=900
```

Receiving it using gstreamer works fine for me:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=9000 caps='application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264' ! \
     rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false
```

For VLC I have created simple SDP file:

```
v=0
m=video 9000 RTP/AVP 96 
c=IN IP4 192.168.1.10
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
```

But after launching it I only get one still frame of the actual stream. When I stop and start VLC, then I receive another frame. Do you know what may be the problem of no continuous stream displaying in VLC?

Answer (score 1):

i faced the same issue and the option "do-timestamp=true" solved it for me

Comment: Which plugin contains the 'do-timestamp' option?